# How to create mask for a float type input in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The rule of input is simple:

Calculation of student grade ...
The inserted notes must go from 0.0 to 10.0 ...

The user can also enter the "f" character to say that the student was missing ...

I was able to block the characters and use the regex to generate the "POINT".

**What are the problems:**

1. Input is not generating the regex correctly, I need to enter 3 characters instead of two for it to insert the point
2. When entering the character f it should block the digit of numbers and vice versa if it enters a number first
3. It is letting you enter more than 3 characters in the input, I know this is in the input attribute, however I left it as 3 to be able to insert the point.

**Functions:**

```
blockCharactersTwo(_event){
    let keyPressed = _event.charCode;
    (keyPressed >= 48 && keyPressed <= 57 || keyPressed === 46 || keyPressed === 102) ? null : _event.preventDefault();
}

convertToDecimal(_element){
    _element.value = _element.value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1.$2") // Insere o PONTO ANTES dos ÚLTIMOS 2 digitos
}
```

**input and output sample:**

```
1) 80 => 8.0   
2) 01 => 0.1  
3) number => block caracter "F"  
4) "f"  => block number  
5) "f"  => if you type "f" do not enter any more characters and not even "f".
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input and expected output please

Comment: I changed the word "mascara" to "mask" as I believed it to be a missed translation. If you are talking about a library or something named "mascara", feel free to roll back the edit :).

Comment: @ChrisLi 
I put it, got better?

Comment: Can the user input `0.1` directly? If yes, what if user enter `10`, will it be interpreted as `1.0`?

Comment: @MatrixTai 
If the user enters with (0) first and then with any number, the (dot) in the middle of the two should be inserted, same as I showed in the example.

now if the user types (1) and then (0) should be 1.0, if the user type (1) (0) (0) should be (10.0)

if the user types (0) (7) will be 0.7,
if the user enters (0) (7) (5) it will be 0.7

If the user types the character ("f") it should be locked so that he can not type any more

Comment: Is this the result u want? https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/5x8zn0wt/ , just a quick draft.

Comment: @MatrixTai 
When I input the following value in order (0) (1) it does not add the point in 0.1, but if I enter a third character, yes, it will boot the point. Do you know why regex happens?

Comment: I do understand what you mean "why regex happens". But `/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/` decompose 100 in to group 1: `1` and group 2: `00` as second group is allowed to have at most 2 characters. Thus I separately handle it in the example. If that's your issue, I will make an answer briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a handler for the keydown event, and a separate one for reformatting, to make it easier. The regex [`/^([fF]{1}|\d{1}\.\d{1}|10\.00?)$/` on regex101.com shows how it works](https://regex101.com/r/0q6uVV/1). The `allNumbersRe` expression just looks for the correct pattern for three numbers.

The trick here is that there is no way to prevent them from entering a value > 10.0, if you want to be able to allow them to enter 100 and format it as 10.0, since the number 100 > 10.0. So, I split the formatting out of the `keydown` handler and added a `blur` handler to do the formatting. It also validates that the formatted number is less than or equal to 10.0. Here I'm using [HTML5 constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) for ease of implementation.

Another thing of note is that I'm using [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), which is a relatively new addition to the standard. It will return strings like "Delete" and "Backspace" for keys that produce non-printable characters. In this case, I'm assuming that any keys that do that are okay to allow (you presumably want to be able to delete the value).

```js
document.querySelector('.grade').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  const char = e.key;
  let newValue = e.target.value;
  if (char.length > 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    newValue += char;
  }
  const perfectRegex = /^([fF]{1}|\d{1}\.\d{1,2}|10\.00?)$/;
  const allNumbersRe = /^(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/;
  const numbersAndDecRe = /^[\d\.]{1,4}$/;
  if (!perfectRegex.test(newValue) && 
    !allNumbersRe.test(newValue) && 
    !numbersAndDecRe.test(newValue) && 
    newValue.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
document.querySelector('.grade').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
  const tenRe = /^100$/;
  const allNumbersRe = /^(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/;
  const newValue = e.target.value;
  e.target.setCustomValidity("");
  if (tenRe.test(newValue)) {
    e.target.value = "10.0";
  } else if (allNumbersRe.test(newValue)) {
    e.target.value = newValue.replace(allNumbersRe, "$1.$2");
  } 
  if (parseFloat(e.target.value) > 10.0) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("The value cannot be more than 10.0");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
input:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="grade" maxlength="4">
```